# Build stability plugin not able to fetch data from jenkins on sonar dashboard

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have downloaded the build stability 1.1.2 and had it installed to my sonar v3.2. However, upon setting up the Cimanagement and userID/password for the jenkins, no build stability chart is showing, any idea? No data is coming over there..

Can anyone help me out over this issue??

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Does anything appear in the Sonar logs? For example are you sure the plugin is activated on startup? I haven't used this plugin but a second thing I'd check is to see if there is an update message as part of the build output (Plugins normally execute as part of the build process). Finally what build technology are you using? some plugins only work with Maven.

Comment: You have to run a new Sonar analysis to see results in the plugin widget.

Comment: ppapapetrou, i have run sonar analysis so many times but it does not work for me.

Comment: Mark,  below are the logs see them and say is anything going wrongway ................. Sensor org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor@f0d3a6...
[INFO] [09:43:43.623] CI URL: Hudson:http://hudson.glassfish.org/job/hudson/
[INFO] [09:43:45.342] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] [09:43:45.342] Retrying request
[INFO] [09:43:46.326] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] [09:43:46.326] Retrying request

Comment: Sonar Logs also showing installation of "Build Stability Plugin"..   what else should i do??

Comment: I found the solution.. Actually i was using "Hudson:http://hudson.glassfish.org/job/hudson/" URL in Cimanagement property in POM.xml this URL was given as an example over "http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin" link whereas i had to use my own job URL in jenkins which is "Hudson:http://10.1.52.136:8080/jenkins/job/Maven_SVN_Trial_1/".

Comment: Please add your solution as answer below, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. Actually i was using "Hudson:hudson.glassfish.org/job/hudson/"; URL in Cimanagement property in POM.xml this URL was given as an example over "docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin"; link whereas i had to use my own job URL in jenkins which is "Hudson:localhost:8080/jenkins/job/Maven_SVN_Trial_1/"